# Razor Code Insert into Database Query

Tags: .net, razor, sql-server-ce

I know this question has been asked, but there have been too many complex answers to solve this issue.  my code is:

```
var ins = db.Execute("INSERT INTO List VALUES(@city, @state, @country)");
```

I have already declared the variables, I have tried different combinations (ex. "@city", '@city', @city) to try and insert the data into the tables.

It works for standard string input to the database but not the variables. is there a way to put these variables in the table?

I am using  SQL Server CE database. Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the [Web Pages Database helper class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database%28v=vs.111%29.aspx). The helper requires that parameters are named in a particular way: @0, @1, @2, etc incrementing by one each time, and then you pass the values in to the Execute method in the same order as they have been declared in the SQL:

```
var ins = db.Execute("INSERT INTO List VALUES (@0, @1, @2)", param1, param2, param3);
```

The official guide to this can be found here: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/data/5-working-with-data